# Open source options for non-English term extraction?

Tags: nlp, information-extraction

I am looking for a open source project that does term extraction with multiple languages.

I have already found [Yahoo BOSS Term Extraction Web Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html), and it is good. However, it does not handle languages other than English.

Are there any open source term extraction projects that support more languages?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific: what kind of terms, and what languages. There is no one-size-fits-all term extraction library, they all specialize in some area (extract people, extract dates, extract political event, extract proteins, ...)

Answer (score 2):

From the packages I've used in production or just played around with, the following were the most comprehensive and most actively maintained:

1. [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) - A computer architecture for a broad range of Natural Language Processing tasks, available under the GNU Public License
2. [Ling-Pipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) (Java) - A suite of Java libraries for the linguistic analysis of human language which can link entity mentions to database entries, uncover relations, cluster documents, ...
3. [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org) (Java) - Java machine learning toolkit for natural language processing (NLP). It supports the most common NLP tasks.
4. [NLTK](http://nltk.org) (Python) - NLTK is a leading platform for building Python programs to work with human language data.
5. [Proxem Antelope](http://www.proxem.com/Default.aspx?tabid=119) (.Net) - Advanced Natural Language Object-oriented Processing Environement
6. [Scala-NLP](http://www.scalanlp.org/) (Scala)
7. [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml) (Java)

Also, there are some good web APIs, such as:

1. [Zemanta](http://www.zemanta.com/blog/yahoo-term-extraction-replacement-api/)
2. [Open-Calais](http://www.opencalais.com)

Answer (score 0):

GATE - General Architecture for Text Engineering: http://gate.ac.uk/

Will do term extraction, keyword sorting and selection, sentiment analysis, all that good stuff.

Open-source, free, from the UK. Does a whole host of languages, including Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Linnaeus](http://linnaeus.sourceforge.net/) -- it is kind of directed to extract species names from scientific papers, but I think you can give it your own dictionaries, and use for other domains/tasks.