# How do I get the context of a sentence?

Tags: nlp

There is a questionnaire that we use to evaluate the student knowledge level (we do this manually, as in a test paper). It consists of the following parts:

1. Multiple choice
2. Comprehension Questions (I.e: Is a spider an insect?)

Now I have been given a task to make an expert system that will automate this. So basically we have a proper answer for this. But my problem is the "comprehension questions". I need to compare the context of their answer to the context of the correct answer.

I already initially searched for the answer, but it seems like it's really a big task to do. What I have search so far is I can do this through NLP which is really new to me. Also, if I'm not mistaken, it seems like that I have to find a dictionary of all words that is possible for the examiner to answer.

Am I on the right track? If no, please suggest of what should I do (study what?) or give me some links to the materials that I need. Also, should I make my own dictionary? Because the words that I will be using are in the Filipino language.

**Update: Comprehension question**

The comprehension section of the questionnaire contains one paragraph explaining a certain scenario. The questions are fairly simple. Here is an example:

Bonnie's uncle told her to pick apples from the tree. Picking up a stick, she poked the fruits so they would fall. In the middle of doing this, a strong gust of wind blew. Due to her fear of the fruits falling on top of her head, she stopped what she was doing. After this, though, she noticed that the wind had caused apples to fall from the tree. These fallen apples were what she brought home to her uncle.

The questions are:

1. What did Bonnie's uncle tell her to do?
2. What caused Bonnie to stop picking apples from the tree?
3. Is Bonnie a good fruit picker? Please explain your answer.

The possible answers that the answer key states are:

For number 1: 
1.1 Bonnie's uncle told her to pick apples from the tree 
1.2 Get apples

For number 2: 
2.1 A strong gust of wind blew 
2.2 She might get hit in the head by the fruits

For number 3: 
3.1 No, because the apples she got were already on the ground 
3.2 No, because the wind was what caused the fruits to fall 
3.3 Yes, because it is difficult to pick fruits when it's windy. 
3.4 Yes, because at least she tried

Now there are answers that were given to me. The job that the system shall be able to do is to compare the context of the student's answer to the context of the right answer in order for the system to successfully be able to grade the student's answer.

Comment: could you please explain the 'comprehension' section a bit more? What are some sample questions? What type of questions are there?

Comment: I suppose if you had questions that only elicited answers like 'No, a spider is not a spider'; You might be able to get a pretty decent accuracy rate. How complex could the answers be?

Comment: The way to make this work best is ask your questions in such a way that only a very limited range of answers can be correct.  This will limit the number of possible correct words to something manageable.  Part of the problem of managing free text answers is you will only ever be able to assign a probability that a human examiner would pass the question if asked to check it.  Shorter answers are much easier to check with higher probability

Comment: @Harry I updated my question for clarification

Comment: Other than harry gave can you please guys give me hint of where can materials that is related to this?

Answer (score 1):

One simplistic way of doing this that I can think of (off the top of my head) is to use a string similarity metric like cosine or jaccard to identify whether certain keywords appear in a test answer and the known correct answer.
Extracting these keywords automatically could be done with [part of speech tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) using NLP. For example, you could extract all nouns (and possibly verbs). Then, representing each answer as a vector of keywords, you could compare the test vector with the known correct vector.

For example, in the second question, the vector for the two possible answers could be

1. gust, wind, blew
2. hit, head, fruits

An answer like "she picked up a stick" with the keywords: picked, stick would have a very low score as compared to something like "afraid of fruit falling on her head" with keywords: fruit, falling, head.

Notes:

1. This can detect only wildly wrong answers. Wrong answers containing the right keywords would not be detected by this technique. :)
2. I'm not sure about non-english sentences. If that is the case, you might want to take every word in the answer as a keyword (removing stopwords).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561612/term-extraction-with-non-english) question might help as well.

Comment: Hmm.. this is a good method.. But is there other way to do this without a risk? And the development and research time is just 4 months.